# How to intercept WebSocket data?

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

In Firefox 57 you can intercept the [body of http requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onBeforeRequest) as well as responses (using [filterResponseData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/filterResponseData)). Is it possible to do the same for web sockets?

Comment: Since Firefox 71, you can view WebSocket messages in the web console but it looks like there is no WebExtension API yet to edit data. You can however edit WebSocket messages with mitmproxy. More information: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=885508#c60 https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/issues/3391

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think you can use the API to look at the WebSocket communication.

The webRequestAPI only applies to the WebSocket handshake, which is still normal HTTP. But once the HTTP upgrade is complete, it will no longer be observable by the API.

To quote from a related [bugfix on Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=129353):

> Support WebSocket in WebRequest API.
>
> This CL makes WebRequest API support intercepting the WebSocket handshake
>   request. Since the handshake is done by means of an HTTP upgrade request, its
>   flow fits into HTTP-oriented WebRequest model. Additional restriction applies,
>   that WS request redirects triggered by extensions are ignored.
>
> Note that WebRequest API does *not intercept*:
>
> - Individual messages sent over an established WebSocket connection.
> - WebSocket closing connection

As Mozilla typically tries to follow the Chrome extension, I would expect that Firefox should behave the same.